# C: Circular Linked List - Add Term To Polynomial

Tags: c, linked-list, polynomials

I am new to circular linked list and I still have some problems with it... I'm trying to make this function in C, in which given a polynomial and two variables (which are e = exponent of x; and c = coefficient) it will add this cx^e to the polynomial. But it has couple of conditions:

1. The polynomial must be in ascending order
2. If there is a term with the same exponent, you should add the terms and not create  another one.
3. You must use a circular linked list, in which its exponents will be the 'headers' of each term.
4. The first term of each polynomial will be of expo = -1, which will be pointing to the second term of the polynomial (expo >= 0) .Also the last term of the polynomial will be pointing to the first term.

I already tried to make this code, but for some reason I don't know, it is compiling with no problem, but it keeps running forever (and it does not give a segmentation fault or anything like that).

Could you guys, please, tell me what I am doing wrong? I really need your help. Sorry, I know it might be a noob thing, but please be patient, I'm pretty new to this.

```
typedef struct Term {
  int expo;
  float coef;
  struct Termo *next; 
 } Term, *Polynomial;


void AddTerm(Polynomial p, int e, float c) { 
/* Add in polynomial 'p' the term '(e,c)', leaving the terms in ascending order */
/* Assume that all c will be different than zero. */
    Polynomial rook, save, term;
    rook = p;

    while(rook -> expo < e){
        save = rook;
        rook = rook -> next;
    }

    term = malloc(sizeof(Term));


    if(rook -> expo == e){
        rook -> coef = rook -> coef + c;
    }
    else{
        term -> expo = e;
        term -> coef = c;
        term -> next = save -> next;
        save -> next = term;
    }

} /* AddTerm */
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I'm running on Linux Mint 17 Cinnammon.

Comment: Try printing `e` before `while` loop and `rook->expo` in every iteration. Or even better, use a debugger to examine those values in runtime. Printing is simpler and faster, but mastering a debugger now will save you a lot of work on more complex projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial list contains a single `Term` with `expo = -1`, and `next` pointing back to itself.  The `while` loop is looking for the first `Term` with `expo` greater-or-equal to the `e` you are trying to add; however, at this point, there is no such `Term`, so the while loop will spin around the circular list forever.  You need the loop to terminate when `rook` comes back around to `p`.

Once you are out of the loop, you only need to allocate a new `Term` if you intend to add it to the list.  In the case where `rook->expo == e`, you don't need a new `Term`.